# segmentation fault when PIN_Init()

Tags: segmentation-fault, instrumentation

all,

I am trying to debug some code that integrates the pin tool. I have found that calling PIN_Init() function leads to a segmentation fault, any suggestion on how to debug this problem? Here is the piece of code:

```
GLOBALFUN int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Init(argc, argv);
  PIN_InitSymbols();
  PIN_Init(argc, argv); //this line is causing the segmentation fault


  INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0);
  PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);

  // Never returns
  PIN_StartProgram();

  return 0; // make compiler happy
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us the implementation of `PIN_Init` ?

Comment: ...I am not much a programmer, and pretty new to Pin. Actually I am not very clear where it is defined... I just downloaded a package here:https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool, then set some env variables to point to the directory. Should this PIN_Init() function be defined in this package?

Comment: What happens if you skip the `Init` function instead of `PIN_Init`?

Comment: After I commented out the Init() function, PIN_Init is still causing the problem. while I think the `Init` should not affect `PIN_Init`? It is just a regular function defined by the programmer.

Comment: ...well, it seems I need to make sure the pin itself work fine, at first...